# UITableView edit mode appears on top of my views

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

[edit mode problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvbON.png)

As you can see in the picture, when I enter the edit mode the delete button appears on top of all the views in the cell.
I assume this is because I am using programmatic UI with autolayouts not the storyboard and some of the constraints are preventing actions, but I cannot find out how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Show your code in which you are laying you constraints so It will be easy to diagnose your problem.

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you want to do. Do you want to hide the delete button? It seems like it might be helpful to see some of the code.

Comment: Hey guys, the answer below solves the problem. Did not know about the contentView. Thanks for trying to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that when creating your `UITableViewCell` subclass, you did not add your custom subviews to the cell's [contentView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623229-contentview).

From the documentation:

> The content view of a UITableViewCell object is the default superview for content that the cell displays. If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view so they position appropriately as the cell transitions in to and out of editing mode.

Sounds like your problem exactly.

Comment: Wow that exactly solves my problem. I had to add views to contentView not self. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @km796 if you found my answer helpful, please mark it as "accepted" and consider giving it an upvote.

Comment: I marked it as accepted. I will upvote once my reputation becomes 15. I cant at the moment.